# Embedding HTTP response into Confluence without HTML Macro

Tags: confluence

**Context:** The HTML Macro is disabled on my company's Confluence.

**Use-case:** Embed content returned by an internal web-site.

**Example:** We have a table that lists various sites we have deployed. We have a Confluence page, with a table describing each, and with a URL to each. 
Each site also supports a "/ping" that tells us it is live. Is there a way to embed the (simple textual) response from that ping as another column, without the use of HTML Macro?

**Stretch goal:** If our REST /ping returns Markup/Markdown  ...is there a way to get some minimal formatting?

Comment: How will you be calling the REST ping from inside your table? What macro are you using?

Comment: That's what I was hoping to do. It does not have to be inside a table. More generally, what macro can I use to get the output of such a REST command to show up somewhere on a Confluence page?

Comment: I initially thought you had a macro that does the rest call, but you wanted another macro that wraps its output to format it. I've added an answer, and I will update it if I come to know any existing plugins since this is sth I am working on this week, but I am implementing my own macro for my case similiar to what I suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on sth similar as well that calls a public rest api to aggregate some results on a confluence page.

Anyways, I am guessing the html macro is disabled in your company  for security reasons. Since you have a specific rest api endpoints, I would suggest that you can create your own custom plugin with a macro. Design it so that the macro can take a param to know which site endpoint to call server side. You can process your requests and let the macro return a string which you can stylize however you want. This is the simplest and cheapest solution (since you won't be paying license fees for a third party addon), and also most secure since you have control over the code.

Is your confluence instance server or cloud? Have you tried asking in the atlassian community forums?

Answer (score 1):

if your company can disable the free alternative then 
use the paid alternative : [adaptavist scriptrunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1215215/scriptrunner-for-confluence?hosting=server&tab=overview) 
script macro